# How to restore javascript value from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

code :

```
Test2 =<input type="text" id="idfield1" name="test2">
<br/> Test3 =<input type="text" id="idfield2" name="test3">
<script>
$('#idfield1').keypress(function() {
  document.getElementById('idfield2').value='text to be displayed' ; 
});
(function(window, document, undefined) {
  function changeSelect(event) {
    if (event.target.type == 'checkbox' || event.target.type == 'radio') {
      window.localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
    } else {
      window.localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.value);
    }
  }

  function load(event) {
    var i = 0,
      k, e;
    while (i < window.localStorage.length) {
      k = window.localStorage.key(i++);
      e = document.getElementById(k);
      if (e) {
        if (e.type == 'checkbox' || e.type == 'radio') {
          e.checked = window.localStorage.getItem(k) == 'checked';
        } else {
          e.value = window.localStorage.getItem(k);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function clearData(event) {
    window.localStorage.clear();
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', load, true);
  window.addEventListener('change', changeSelect, true);
  window.addEventListener('select', changeSelect, true);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', changeSelect, true);
  window.addEventListener('click', changeSelect, true);
  window.addEventListener('submit', clearData, true);
})(window, document)
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxc156ox/6/

I want to restore values of input when ever browser is accidentally closed or reloaded .

Multiple values coming form javscript based on user input.If user accidentally closed page ,due to internet his page was reloaded in the sense all values should restore from localstorage.

when you reload text3 values is not coming .text2 value is coming

Please help me to get the value in any way .I am working on this form a long long time .Any help would be very useful.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: @Raze no error no data

Comment: Can you enter window.localStorage in the console and check its contents?

Comment: It is working fine at my end. As i typed something in text2 then "text to be displayed" came up in text3. But as soon as you type something in text3 and reload the page. It is displaying the old data.

Comment: @Eshu i dont want to type on text3 it should load value while typing on text2 .while reloaded it should the same value what it loaded on typing text2 .

Comment: @Karthika, Do you want it dynamic, I mean for any number of fields or only for these two?

Comment: Actually the problem is with your changeSelect function. You need to update this function only.

Comment: @Eshu I need any number of fields .

Comment: Check first is variable going to local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below fiddle link will solve you issue.

[Check it.](http://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/wvd68zzo/3/)

```
            $('#idfield1').keypress(function(evt) {
      document.getElementById('idfield2').value=evt.currentTarget.value ; 
    });
    (function(window, document, undefined) {
      function changeSelect(event) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        //For query selection use below code
        //var element = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
        for(var index=0; index<elements.length; index++){
            if (elements[index].type == 'checkbox' || elements[index].type == 'radio') {
            window.localStorage.setItem(elements[index].id, elements[index].checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
          } else {
            window.localStorage.setItem(elements[index].id, elements[index].value);
          }
        }
      }

      function load(event) {
        var i = 0,
          k, e;
        while (i < window.localStorage.length) {
          k = window.localStorage.key(i++);
          e = document.getElementById(k);
          if (e) {
            if (e.type == 'checkbox' || e.type == 'radio') {
              e.checked = window.localStorage.getItem(k) == 'checked';
            } else {
              e.value = window.localStorage.getItem(k);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function clearData(event) {
        window.localStorage.clear();
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', load, true);
      window.addEventListener('change', changeSelect, true);
      window.addEventListener('select', changeSelect, true);
      window.addEventListener('keyup', changeSelect, true);
      window.addEventListener('click', changeSelect, true);
      window.addEventListener('submit', clearData, true);
    })(window, document)
```

Comment: Sorry for that, i made a mistake in drafting it. Please check now.

Comment: It working suberb but it not working with textarea and select .

Comment: Yes you need to update the change function just comment the line: var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), with var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select")